# Не вызывается js функция при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется код

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function delPost($num) {
  x=confirm("Вы действительно хотите удалить пост?");
  if (x==true) {
  window.location.href = линк
                }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript: delPost(1)" value="тест"></input>
</body>
```

Однако при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит, хотя должно вылазить окно подтверждения.

Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: Посчитайте количество закрывающих фигурных скобок.

Comment: Советую отказаться от onclick в js, в пользу jquery, дабы не городить не нужные заборы в самом html. Это стоит учесть, если вы стремитесь к новшеству и современным методам разработки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посчитай сколько у тебя открытых { и закрытых }.

Это что такое javascript: ?

Есть отличный инструмент-Firebug

Comment: блин, точно, совсем я что-то с ума посходил :) привык уже, что php на такие ошибки тыкает пальцем)))

я читал, что javascript: - указание протокола, через которое производится действие. Или это не нужно указывать?

Comment: необязательно, поставте firebug или хотябы гуглхром, там он встроен уже

Comment: у меня-то стоит хром. IEшники будут в порядке?

Comment: с этим скриптом -- да)

Comment: с этим - в смысле с javascript: ? ))

Comment: >привык уже, что php на такие ошибки тыкает пальцем)))
Дык если у вас норм браузер то зайдите в ***Консоль ошибок*** :)

Answer (score 1):

Какие еще `$num`??? хоть синтаксис почитайте..
И еще лишняя } в конце

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="delPost(1)" value="тест"></input>

<script>
function delPost(num) {
  x=confirm("Вы действительно хотите удалить пост?");
  if (x==true) {
  window.location.href = "линк";
                }
}
</script>​
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно указывать в начале `javascript:`, если используется JavaScript. Например так `<a href="javascript:delPost(1);">[X]</a>`.